# Unable to install Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've done all commands but the loading continues.. seems that I got errors during my installation

```
hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 
02288e089196d0c7    offline

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 
02288e089196d0c7    offline

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb reboot bootloader
error: device offline
hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ ./adb sideload
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 
02288e089196d0c7    offline

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ ./adb sideload 
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 
02288e089196d0c7    sideload

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 
02288e089196d0c7    recovery

hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ ubuntu-device-flash --list-channels
devel-proposed (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed)
devel-proposed-customized (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed-customized)
ubuntu-touch/saucy
ubuntu-touch/saucy-customized
ubuntu-touch/trusty
ubuntu-touch/trusty-customized
ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed-customized-generic
devel (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic)
devel-customized-generic (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-customized-generic)
trusty-proposed-customized-demo
ubuntu-touch/saucy-proposed-customized
ubuntu-touch/saucy-surfaceflinger
ubuntu-touch/trusty-proposed-customized
ubuntu-touch/utopic-customized
saucy
saucy-customized
trusty
trusty-customized
ubuntu-touch/devel-proposed (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed)
ubuntu-touch/devel-proposed-customized (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed-customized)
ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed-customized-demo
saucy-proposed-customized
saucy-surfaceflinger
trusty-proposed-customized
ubuntu-touch/devel (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic)
ubuntu-touch/devel-customized-generic (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-customized-generic)
ubuntu-touch/trusty-proposed-customized-demo
ubuntu-touch/utopic-customized-demo
devel-proposed-customized-generic (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed-customized-generic)
trusty-customized-demo
ubuntu-touch/devel-proposed-customized-demo (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed-customized-demo)
ubuntu-touch/stable (alias to ubuntu-touch/stable)
ubuntu-touch/trusty-customized-generic
ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed
ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed-customized
devel-customized (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-customized)
ubuntu-touch/devel-customized-demo (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-customized-demo)
ubuntu-touch/saucy-proposed
ubuntu-touch/trusty-proposed
ubuntu-touch/trusty-proposed-customized-generic
ubuntu-touch/utopic
ubuntu-touch/utopic-customized-generic
stable (alias to ubuntu-touch/stable)
trusty-customized-generic
ubuntu-touch/devel-proposed-customized-generic (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed-customized-generic)
ubuntu-touch/trusty-customized-demo
saucy-proposed
trusty-proposed
trusty-proposed-customized-generic
ubuntu-touch/devel-customized (alias to ubuntu-touch/utopic-customized)
hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $  ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel-proposed
2014/06/12 18:33:13 Expecting the device to expose an adb interface...
2014/06/12 18:33:13 Device is |mako|
2014/06/12 18:33:16 Flashing version 79 from devel-proposed channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device mako
2014/06/12 18:33:16 ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed is a channel alias to devel-proposed
2014/06/12 18:33:21 Start pushing /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-8e3e30aa503cbe9b6fdf3497ad5cf38398f8bcf88c80d98a988a4ad464b3db28.tar.xz to device
2014/06/12 18:33:21 Start pushing /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/devel-proposed/mako/version-79.tar.xz to device
2014/06/12 18:33:21 Start pushing /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2014/06/12 18:33:21 Start pushing /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
224.00 KB / 334.17 MB [_______________________________] 0.07 % 983.71 KB/s 5m47s2014/06/12 18:33:21 Done pushing /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2014/06/12 18:33:21 Done pushing /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/devel-proposed/mako/version-79.tar.xz to device
2014/06/12 18:33:21 Done pushing /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2.05 MB / 334.17 MB [________________________________] 0.61 % 208.21 KB/s 27m13s2014/06/12 18:33:31 Done pushing /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-8e3e30aa503cbe9b6fdf3497ad5cf38398f8bcf88c80d98a988a4ad464b3db28.tar.xz to device
334.17 MB / 334.17 MB [====================================] 100.00 % 1.07 MB/s 
2014/06/12 18:38:33 Start pushing /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-473f9aa1f2618d7eee30e116491b01ec5815baa7b9a7b7c02afb88896c15f041.tar.xz to device
2014/06/12 18:39:50 Done pushing /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-473f9aa1f2618d7eee30e116491b01ec5815baa7b9a7b7c02afb88896c15f041.tar.xz to device
2014/06/12 18:39:50 Created ubuntu_command: /home/hanafi81/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu_commands665141130
2014/06/12 18:39:50 Rebooting into recovery to flash
```

Comment: The only command that actually initiated the flash was the last one, and that looked successful. What did it do after the "Rebooting into recovery to flash"?

Comment: Have you tried **ubuntu-device-flash** (and your choice of channel) with option **--bootstrap** (at least once) for this device? *What were you attempting with **sideload**?*

Comment: nothing happens.. it keep loading purple screen with ubuntu logo.. i've done sudo adb sideload <filename> yet unable to boot..

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4 (running Stock Android 4.4.3) in a Dual Boot mode so that I can always switch back to Android when I am not tinkering with Ubuntu Touch.

Its worth a look. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation

```bsh
hanafi81@hanafi81 ~ $ adb reboot bootloader
error: device offline
```

Can happen when you have not enabled the Android Debugging.

**Enable USB debugging on your device.**

On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.

On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.

Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Refer to http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. I found out another major problem; 1) unable to mount sdcard 2) nothing loads after recovery 3) unable to push any img via sudo adb push sideload 4) bricked Nexus 4 as far as I'm concern now

Comment: @hilmi07,
Please download the factory image from 
<https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occamktu84l >

There would be one sh/cmd inside the tar which you can execute if you have all the right tools installed.

And you phone will come back to life. Next you can follow the instructions for Dual boot.

Answer (score 1):

Installation is successful after several attempt. I restart adb start-server, and wipe cache plus factory setting. Last, I begin installation process as quoted in ubuntu wiki. And it's done.